# access, how to access a value of combo box

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a combo box in ms access 2010.
Combo box has 3 values.
for example: admin, user, super_user; and are stored in table type.

In another table/view I input users. 
and one field is combo box where I can select 1 or more user types.

**My Requirement:**
I want to create macro->

```
IF [USERS].[TYPE] = admin, then do something ON INSERT.
```

-but I can't access that element. 
I tried with:

```
([USERS].[TYPE].[Value])1 = "admin"
([USERS].[TYPE].[Value])1 = 1
[USERS].[TYPE].Value(1) = "admin"
[USERS].[TYPE].[Value]1
[USERS].[TYPE].Column(1) = 1
.........................
.............
```

and much more variation(different combinations), but I can't see what value is selected.

Using query wizard I built query like this:

```
SELECT korisnici.vrsta.Value
FROM korisnici
WHERE (((korisnici.vrsta.Value)=1));
```

and result is 'administrator'

does somebody knows how to access that value of combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution: 
Data macros cannot process multi-valued or attachment data-types.

from here:
 http://www.365advisor.com/ArticleContenta14b8953b11bec36

tnx to all..

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this : Forms!MyFormName!MyColumnName.Column(1)

Don't forgot the first column is 0 and not 1

Comment: what is "forms" here? And why ! instead of .?  i tryed these: Table!columnName!column(1), and access converts it by saving to [mainTable]![columnName]![column](1)